# How do I count the number of instances from 2 columns where a given string appears?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

Here's an example table:

```
games_table
----------------------------------------------------
|   home_team   |   away_team   |   game_outcome   |
----------------------------------------------------
|    Chelsea    |    Arsenal    |     Home wins    |
----------------------------------------------------
|    Everton    |   Liverpool   |     Away wins    |
----------------------------------------------------
|    Arsenal    |    Chelsea    |     Home wins    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

What I need is the number of times 'Chelsea' appears `WHERE game_outcome = 'Home wins'` which is 2 in this example.

Normally this would be very easy but I'm stuck because I have to search 2 columns.
I really need some insight.

Comment: As Andrew answered already (correct imho :)) I am still wondering why you want to count in your example 2 times Chelsea and home wins, because in this case Chelsea win once and lost once.

Comment: Or perhaps what you're after is: `SELECT * FROM games_table g WHERE (home_team='Chelsea' AND game_outcome='Home wins') OR (away_team='Chelsea' AND game_outcome='Away wins')`

Comment: @YvesR
Good question. This was a simplified example but really I'm counting the number of correct predictions of the game outcome for team Chelsea, given the prediction is 'Home wins'. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   games_table
WHERE  game_outcome = 'Home wins'
AND    (home_team = 'Chelsea' OR away_team = 'Chelsea')
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple and elegant.

Comment: `AND 'Chelsea' IN ( home_team , away_team )`